# How to check TIMESTAMP format in SQL?

Tags: sql, timestamp, rdbms

What's the best way to check if the VARIANT TYPE with JSONs with value similar to TIMESTAMP_NTZ has correct format?

For example, this is the correct format that I would like to have

```
 2020-12-26T12:12:11.215581Z
```

but there are times when it looks different in database, like this

```
2021-11-26T12:12:11.215581Z[UTC]
```

I would like to detect records which are in a different format than the reference.

I tried with simple LIKE, but it omits formats that could be different than this.

```
LIKE '%[UTC]%'
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products have their own, non-ANSI functions.)

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: Does it need to have exactly 6 digits after decimal (or any decimal portion at all)?

Comment: A column defined with the data type `timestamp` does not have any "format". So you don't have to "check" it because it won't allow to store invalid values.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry generally it is VARIANT TYPE with JSONs, so I would like to check if specific key has this correct value format.

Comment: @SalmanA I am not 100% sure, but probably yes

Comment: Well, then it's not a "timestamp" column, but a string/text column containing something that is supposed to be a timestamp. If you had chosen a proper data type, you wouldn't have this problem to begin with.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are right, but sometimes happens that this value has different format than I expecting, so I would like to detect such situations. So should I use regex or something else?

Comment: Please tag the rdbms. Regex is needed.

Comment: The <rdbms> tag is a _general_ tag, but here we need the tag for the specific dbms product you're using. (Different products have different functionality.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a regular expression to check the equality of the desired format. I will extend this answer if the rdbms is known.

```
[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{6}Z
```

**MySQL & SQLite**:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE timestamp not REGEXP '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{6}Z';
```

**Oracle**:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE not REGEXP_LIKE(timestamp, '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{6}Z');
```

Comment: Of course it fails to catch dates like '2022-02-29T...'

Comment: May you clarify, why this should fail on a leap date?

Comment: It passes regex but it will fail (or do something unexpected) when someone actually tries to cast it to a datetime (e.g. this `select cast('2022-02-29T12:12:11.215581Z' as datetimeoffset)` will fail on on SQL server).

Comment: I derived from the questions comment section that the column is of type string/text. So no need to pay attention to the tedious handling of certain dates. Op asked how to determine different formats, not how to cast those strings.

Answer (score 0):

If all the records you want to detect come in addition to the end of the format that should be then you can use length.

Basically:

```
WHERE NOT len(column_name)=27
```

27 because your correct format **2020-12-26T12:12:11.215581Z** has 27 characters.

Comment: Thanks is a solution, but if we assume it can have fewer digits, it might be better to check if it ends with 'Z'

Comment: You're right. You can check the end letter too.  Good luck with.